# SELECT DISTINCT ON (geometry column) equivalent with GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to create a Django query that will do the equivalent of the following PostgreSQL/PostGIS query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (site) * FROM some_table;
```

`site` is a `POINT` type geometry column. How can this be done?

Basically, many of the records in `some_table` share the same `POINT` geometry; I just want a list of the geometries with no duplicates. I don't care about the rest of the `some_table` columns.

The rest of my query is pretty simple; it looks something like this:

```
qs = models.SomeTable.objects.filter(foo='bar', site__contained=some_polygon)
```

Side note:

The 'manager' for SomeTable (`SomeTable.objects`) is a `django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeoManger` type. I don't know if that helps at all.

Relevant version info:

- Django 1.3
- PostgreSQL 9.1.1
- PostGIS 1.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had overlooked `distinct`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Here's the django query that does exactly what I need:

```
qs = models.SomeTable.objects.filter(foo='bar', site__contained=some_polygon).values('site').distinct()
```